# Is it possible to remove extra html added when using content blocks in Marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template

I have an email that has to be sent, I am a developer, but not an MC consultant
The problem is that when we create an email message & paste our email html code, everything works fine

When we create an email message & paste the html code in a content block & add it to our email message,  the email start to look a bit different in some Outlook desktop versions

When inspecting the html code in the browser I noticed that my email template html is wrapped by another table

[image]

Since it is the only change that exists between the two email messages, I am assuming that this extra html is the problem

My question is : Can we remove that extra html added ?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: For me, the class looks like from a template. Can you check the current template which was using in that email?

Comment: @duyduc27 Yes, I checked, but that class does not exist in my html template, I feel like it is added when using the content block

Comment: go to your email, click Properties. Your current template for that email is on the left panel. Then you need to find it and check out whether the class was from that template. Sometimes in old email still has cached template then you may need to update it.

Comment: The creation method was HTML, so I did not use MC email template .. I created email message, then crated a content block that has the email template ( html/css ), and added it to my email message, so in Properties, I don't see the email template in the left side, am I mistaken ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using content blocks, all the blocks outside the Code Snippet block will wrap itself in what I call a 'component table' of automatically created HTML that SFMC creates in an attempt to be helpful. If this HTML is causing issues, your best solution would be to change those content blocks you are calling in to Code Snippets (Even the HTML block will wrap in the component table) instead and then use those in the email.

By shifting to code snippets, this will remove the capability of anything other than custom coding though, so that is something to keep in mind.